# Flex Mobile 4.6 Sqlite Date Range Query Not Working Inside Flex/Flash Builder or on Device

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, actionscript, sqlite

The app I'm working on allows users to create logs for specific days.  I am trying to pull back information based a certain date range.

Here's the code to create the table (slimmed down for the purposes of this post):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TimeLogged(
    ...
    LogDate DATE NOT NULL
);
```

The code used to insert the date into the table is:

```
INSERT INTO TimeLogged (LogDate) VALUES (date('2012-01-14'));
```

Here's the query I'm using to get the date range:

```
SELECT LogDate FROM TimeLogged WHERE LogDate BETWEEN date('2012-01-01') AND date('2012-04-16')
```

It works perfectly from the Sqlite Command Window.  Here's a link since I'm too new to post pix:
[Sqlite Command Window](http://www.planetlizard.com/so/cmd.png)

Here's the code I use in Flex/Flash Builder 4.6 to get back the results:

```
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = SQLCom.SQLCon;
            stmt.text = "SELECT LogDate FROM TimeLogged WHERE LogDate BETWEEN date('2012-01-01') AND date('2012-04-16')";
            try{
                stmt.execute();
            }
            catch(err:SQLError){
                trace(err.details);
            }

            var a:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(stmt.getResult().data);

            trace("a.length: " + a.length);

            for(var i:int = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
                trace("a[" + i + "]: " + a[i].LogDate);
```

I get no results back even though there are multiple records.

Here is what I get in the Console output when I remove the WHERE/BETWEEN statement:
[Flex/Flash Builder Console output](http://www.planetlizard.com/so/flex.png)

Thank you in advance to anyone who can shed some light on my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that works.  I created a function to convert the UTC day to Julian Day:

```
protected function UTCToJulianDay(d:Date):Number {
    return ((( d.time - (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000))  / 86400000) + 2440587.5);
}
```

Then I just run each date object through the function:

```
var d:Date = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() - (86400000 * 7));// first day is one week prior

var d1:Number = UTCToJulianDay(d);
var d2:Number = UTCToJulianDay(new Date());
```

So the date objects just go into the query as follows (refer to original post for full code):

```
stmt.text = "SELECT LogDate FROM TimeLogged WHERE LogDate BETWEEN " + d1 + " AND " + d2;
```